# bash exits immediately after adding kubectl bash completion

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, sh

`bash` exits immediately to solve this problem I had press `ALT+F2` and then set terminal to `sh` rather than `bash`. I ran `sh` and commented out the section which I added for kubectl bash completion:

```
source <(kubectl completion bash)
```

Now in `sh` when I enter `bash` it displays `kubectl` usage:

```
bash <search term> [-h] [-c] [-n] [-t] [-l] [-d] [-p] [-s] [-b] [-k] [-v] [-r] [-i] -- tail multiple Kubernetes pod logs at the same time
...
```

Why this happens? I even tried to reinstall `bash` but it again exits unexpectedly! How should I fix this issue?

`~/.bashrc` content:

```
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
#source <(kubectl completion bash)
```

**`~/.bashprofile` file does not exist.**

`~/.profile` file content:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

The output of the `grep` command is as follow:

```
$ grep -H kube ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null
/home/MyUserName/.bashrc:#source <(kubectl completion bash)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify a few things. Are you talking about `sh` or about `bash`? They are not the same thing. What is the output of `kubectl completion bash` that you are sourcing? We need to see that to understand why it is exiting. And what shell are you running that in? I assume `bash` since `source` is a bash thing and doesn't exist in `sh`.

Comment: @terdon I edited my question to clarify bash/sh further. `kubectl` output is very long so I cannot put the whole output here. Moreover I have commented it out via `sh` terminal. (I don't have access to bash)

Comment: You have commented _what_ out _where_? Can you show us your current `~/.bashrc` and ~/.bash_profile`, if it exists, and `~/.profile` if it doesn't?

Comment: @terdon please kindly take a look. As I explained in the question I have commented out `source <(kubectl completion bash)` from ~/.bashrc

Comment: Then this is really strange. Maybe you have added something in another file too? Does this command give any output: `grep -H kube ~/.bashrc ~/.profile ~/.bash_profile ~/bash.login ~/.bash_aliases /etc/bash.bashrc /etc/profile /etc/profile.d/* /etc/environment 2> /dev/null`? And I assume the problem persists after a reboot or loging out?

Comment: @terdon I don't have access to system at the time being, but I will send it tomorrow. thanks.

Comment: ... `/etc/bash_completion.d/*` might be worth a look also

Comment: @steeldriver good point! I will also take a look at it and report back the results. :)

Comment: @steeldriver thank you! There was a file in `/etc/bash_completion.d/` for `kubernetes`. By deleting the file problem solved and bash is working! Thanks. Please send your comment as an answer for future users.

Comment: @steeldriver or Alireza, just a kind remind if this deserves an answer :).